How do I make water level smoother with Flip Fluids?
I'm using the Flip Fluids addon. In my animation I have a liquid slowly spilling over a flat surface. I want to make the fluid surface as smooth as possible so that I can use it to show the reflection of a bckground object in it. The problem is that I still have these micro ripples on the fluid surface and I don't know how to get rid of them or make them less visible. I think I've tried everything, increasing the resolution, playing with viscosity and surface tension settings, switching between "inflow" and "fluid" for simulation input, changing the height and distance of my flow object, and nothing works.
The images below are probably my best result yet, made at 512 resolution with surface tension at 1 and viscosity at .05.



Hello have you thought about making your water with a simple subdivided plane and a Displace modifier or a noise plugged into a Bump node?

@moonboots No because over the course of the animation I need to gradually cover the surface that is under the liquid.

I don't know well the liquid sim, but I think only the surface tension or viscosity can help you. In real life, the surface would be smooth only at a very small scale where surface tension is stronger. Imagine the area of your render is at the scale of a city, the surface wouldn't be smooth anywhere, too much waves and turbulences.

If you need the fluid to move, it will make waves (you can't avoid that). If you have more viscosity, waves will be less, but fluid will stick more and flow less. If you can find any sort of "dampening", that's probably the way to make waves dissipate faster.
